# AWS route 53 redirection with new domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

We are currently migrating from one domain to another domain, e.g `www.example.co.uk` to `www.example-dev.co.uk`

Currently `www.example.co.uk` point to ELB which has the target server, it then proxy's the request to kubernetes cluster where we have our microservices.

Could you please suggest how can I achieve this, so anybody who hits `www.example.co.uk` should be redirected to `www.example-dev.co.uk`

I came across S3 redirection, but we are not using `index.html` page to server, our application is on kubernetes on ec2 nodes.

Comment: What type of ELB are you using? Application Load Balancer [supports redirects](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/07/elastic-load-balancing-announces-support-for-redirects-and-fixed-responses-for-application-load-balancer/). Either way you can't do it in Route 53 as redirects are HTTP level, not DNS level.

Comment: Can't you just create another record set in the `example-dev.co.uk` hosted zone that points to the Load Balancer in the same way that the current record does? If both domain names are hosted in Amazon Route 53, that should be no problem. This would simply mean that both domain names resolve to the same target, rather than doing any "redirection".